# Excel return values from other columns based on current value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wonder if anyone has any idea of how to do this in Excel. I could easily do this in SQL with lead/lag functions.

I have table like this.

[image]

I would like to add 2 columns which return their last items and their prices, like below.
[image]

Comment: So what did you try? Look into XLOOKUP, try and if you don't succeed, post your attempts here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following in cell `E1`:

```
=LET(in,A2:C8, seq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(in)), cust,TAKE(in,,1),
 idx,MAP(cust,seq,LAMBDA(c,s,XMATCH(c,FILTER(cust,seq<s,""),,-1))),
 out,IF(ISNA(idx),"",INDEX(DROP(in,,1),idx,{1,2})),
 VSTACK({"Previous Item","Previous Price"},out))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

Basically on each iteration of `MAP` it filters by previous items, then use `XMATCH` with reverse search input argument (`-1`). For those rows the previous item was not found, `MAP` returns `#N/A`, so `out` checks this situation to return an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It would to have more details about this. Do you have a date for each purchase/item? Do you want sort this by just the price? You can use the Lag function here. This is an example

```
LAG(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Customers ORDER BY X) AS Previous_Price
```

I try this in Snowflake

```
select NAME,
       PRICE,
       DEVICE,
       LAG(PRICE) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY PRICE) AS PREVIOUS_PRICE,
       LAG(DEVICE) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY PRICE) AS PREVIOUS_DEVICE
from(
select 'Jack' as NAME,'TV' as DEVICE,10 as PRICE
union
select 'Jack' as NAME,'APPLE' as DEVICE,20 as PRICE
union
select 'Peter' as NAME,'TV' as DEVICE,40 as PRICE
)
```

Comment: The OP is not looking for a Google sheets solution